# My HTML files don't look right

Tags: html, validation

I'm a very new developer so I apologize in advance if this question seems silly or if the answer is obvious.

I'm trying to make a website from HTML with data validation, but I'm having trouble.

This code seemed like it would be good to use:  http://runnable.com/UZJ24Io3XEw2AABU/how-to-validate-forms-in-jquery-for-validation

When I run the code on the site the result looks like right and the validation works.

But when I put the code into an HTML file and open it, my result is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrQH9.jpg

And the validation does not work.

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm not sure why this is.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: .. Best advice to a new developer is to break into it, start finding out why it doesn't work. Using another person's code always presents the risk of getting broken code. Another route is to just take pieces and Frankenstein together your own version of it

Comment: Start at the beginning. Does the Javascript run at all? If you put an `alert` in the source, do you get an alert? Are there errors in the error console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're looking at has a lot of external resources; css and javascript. You have to make sure that you are properly linking to and loading all those resources.

I notice that there is one local style sheet:

`<link href="runnable.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

That looks to be what you're missing in your styles. You can save that code and put the .css file in the same directory as your html file, or you can add that code to your head tag:

```
<style>
.label {
width:100px;
text-align:right;
float:left;
padding-right:10px;
font-weight:bold;
}
#register-form label.error {
color:#FB3A3A;
font-weight:bold;
}
h1 {
font-family: Helvetica;
font-weight: 100;
color:#333;
padding-bottom:20px;
}
</style>
```